# Is there a way to get Visual Studio to provide intellisense for late-bound objects in classic ASP?

Tags: visual-studio, asp-classic, vbscript, intellisense, late-binding

I'm working on a Classic ASP (with VB Script) project where I'm instantiating an object from an ActiveX control like so:

```
Dim objHelper
Set objHelper = Server.CreateObject("HelperLib.HelperObj")
```

Visual Studio 2005 provides intellisense for the first "layer" of properties and methods, but it can't seem to see properties and methods that are members of the main objects.  For example:

```
objHelper.               'Properties and methods show up after the period   '
objHelper.FirstProperty. 'No properties and methods are shown after the period'
```

Is there a way to "help" Visual Studio in some way to see these object types so that I can work in a more strongly-typed environment?

Comment: What's the static type of the property?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, 2005 does not do this.  2008 does a very good job of it, however.  Once you install sp1, that is.

Comment: I tried opening it in VS 2010 and ended up with the same functionality as VS 2005.  Is there something I need to do to get VS to "look deeper"?